# Getting error while running the code

Tags: python

Hi all don't know whether it is repeated question or not.

```
f = open( "data/summarizetext.txt", "r" )
lines = []
for line in f:
lines.append(line)
f.close()
lines = lines.replace('\r', '')
print(lines)
```

but when i run the code showing

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` method is to be used with strings, not with lists. To perform the action on every string in your list, you can use a simple list comprehension.

This will work:

```
lines = [[x.replace('\r', '') for x in y] for y in lines]
```

Comment: it is giving  only []

Comment: @AtanuMandal You will need to provide us with the contents of your file/list then.

Comment: ['a', 'close', 'up', 'of', 'a', 'person', 'holding', 'a', 'pair', 'of', 'scissors']
 ['a', 'close', 'up', 'of', 'a', 'person', 'on', 'a', 'pair', 'of', 'skis']
 ['a', 'close', 'up', 'of', 'a', 'person', 'holding', 'a', 'pair', 'of', 'skis']

Comment: @AtanuMandal Is it a list of lists?

Comment: exactly. what i need to be done is to create a sentence using the following words.

Comment: @AtanuMandal Updated my answer to reflect the list of lists :)

Comment: i have added a answer

Answer (score 0):

[['[', "'", 'a', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'c', 'l', 'o', 's', 'e', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'u', 'p', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'o', 'f', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'a', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'p', 'e', 'r', 's', 'o', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'h', 'o', 'l', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'g', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'a', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'p', 'a', 'i', 'r', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'o', 'f', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 's', 'c', 'i', 's', 's', 'o', 'r', 's', "'", ']', '', ' ', '[', "'", 'a', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'c', 'l', 'o', 's', 'e', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'u', 'p', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'o', 'f', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'a', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'p', 'e', 'r', 's', 'o', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'o', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'a', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'p', 'a', 'i', 'r', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'o', 'f', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 's', 'k', 'i', 's', "'", ']', '', ' ', '[', "'", 'a', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'c', 'l', 'o', 's', 'e', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'u', 'p', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'o', 'f', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'a', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'p', 'e', 'r', 's', 'o', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'h', 'o', 'l', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'g', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'a', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'p', 'a', 'i', 'r', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'o', 'f', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 's', 'k', 'i', 's', "'", ']', '', '\n']]

is now the result :P

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `lines` is a list, whereas the `replace` method is for `str`s.

Change your line with `replace` to:

```
lines = [line.replace('\r', '') for line in lines]
```

This will concatenate a list of strings and apply the `replace` call to each of those strings.